# Not printing variable in java/eclipse console is terminated

Tags: java, eclipse, google-drive-api

Im trying to print the permissions on a certain file in Google Drive.
When running the code the console does not print out our results, it just says .

Is there something wrong with this part? :

`System.out.println(permissions.getItems());`

Iv'e tried a couple of things but i can't get why it won't print it out.

```
public class GoogleDriveListPermission {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, URISyntaxException {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File("eclipsejava-kjd7991s.p12"))
        .setServiceAccountUser("admin@domain.com")
        .setServiceAccountId("8969872333158-oj1ioad24f9t89da7sdfyhj2k@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))    
        .build();


        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google Drive App1")
            .build();

}
  public static String fileId = "12u4QfIIOkM9rpoQvSrstMI8-3EJvZYp3jw1Gp3NSz";
  public static String newOwner = "113598691748107335"; 

  public static List<Permission> retrievePermissions(Drive service,
          String fileId) {
        try {
          PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId).execute();

          System.out.println(permissions.getItems());

          return permissions.getItems();


        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        }

        return null;
      }



}
```

Comment: Execute the code with your debugger, and you'll know. That said, it doesn't seem that your program ever calls retrievePermissions().

Comment: What do you expect to see printed when you println a Java List object? You will normally iterate the list and print a property from each of its objects. You might want to start by println ing the count of returned properties.